# Chromedriver launching data;; browser after updating to V100 (both chromedriver and Chrome browser)

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I'm running automated test scripts using webdriver.io. Issue is, the code stopped running after updating the chromedriver to 100.0.4896.60 which is recommended for chrome browser v100 that is currently installed. It was working fine in all the previous versions (v93 thru v99). Im getting the data;; screen and I dont see any errors on the terminal (VS Code)

I wont be able to upgrade or downgrade the browser versions. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It was a case of access issues with DevTools of chrome. After getting proper access the issue is resolved.